# Best way to do powerOf(int x, int n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, big-o

So given x, and power, n, solve for `X^n`.
There's the easy way that's `O(n)`...
I can get it down to `O(n/2)`, by doing

```
numSquares = n/2;
numOnes = n%2;
return (numSquares * x * x + numOnes * x);
```

Now there's a `O(log(n))` solution, does anyone know how to do it? It can be done recursively.

Comment: It doesn't need to be done recursively; it can be done with simple iteration.

Comment: Are you aware O(n/2) is the same as O(n)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you know that x<sup>a+b</sup> = x<sup>a</sup> x<sup>b</sup> so...

```
int pow(int x, unsigned int y)
{
  if (y == 0) return 1;
  if (y == 1) return x;
  int a = y / 2;
  int xa = pow(x, a);
  if (a + a == y) // y even
    return xa * xa;
  else
    return xa * xa * x;
}
```

Comment: you also need a `if (y<0) { return (x==1)?1:0; }` and to throw an exception for `y<0, x==0`

Comment: Recursion for something already so computationally expensive as calculating the power of a number seems a tad bit overkill

Comment: What's overkill about recursion exactly? Also, it's not computationally expensive, it has O(lg(n)) run time.

Comment: I should have said computationally intensive, sorry about that. The function isn't tail-call optimizable, and I have a suspicion the function call overhead here would be comparable to the execution time of each call.

Comment: If he wants to make micro-optimisations then that's up to him. I'm presenting something that is elegant so as to demonstrate the concept. Recursive solutions are almost always easier to understand that iterative ones.

Answer (score 17):

The mathematical concept that can be exploited is that `x2n+1 = x2n ⋅ x` and `x2n = xn ⋅ xn`.

Answer (score 9):

The usual implementation is something along these lines (cribbed from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)):

```
long power(long x, unsigned long n)
{
    long result = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        /* n is odd, bitwise test */ 
        if (n & 1) {
            result *= x;
        }
        x *= x;
        n /= 2;     /* integer division, rounds down */
    }
    return result;
}
```

Recursion isn't necessary or (I'd say) particularly desirable, although it can win on obviousness:

```
long power(long x, unsigned long n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    long result = power(x, n/2); // x ^ (n/2)
    result *= result;            // x ^ (n/2)*2
    if (n & 1) result *= x;      // x ^ n
    return result;
}
```

Of course in any version you overflow a long pretty quickly. You can apply the same algorithms to your favourite bigint representation, although any bigint library is going to include an integer power function already.

Both versions of the function above return 1 for `power(0,0)`. You may or may not consider this a bug.

Comment: Fun fact: g77 uses exponentiation by squaring to calculate integral powers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find an explanation here: [Fast exponentiation](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/12/10/fast-exponentiation/). For some values of n, you can calculate x^n with fewer multiplications than by using the powers of two trick.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to generate the powers of x in sequence x<sup>2</sup>, x<sup>4</sup>, x<sup>8</sup>, x<sup>16</sup>, x<sup>32</sup>, ... and include those that are needed in the result.

Comment: unless i'm not getting your answer, you can't do this infinitely though right?

Comment: @Mike: You can only do anything infinitely if you have an infinite computer, and most of us are stuck with ordinary, very finite computers.  If you use a multi-precision arithmetic package, you can work with numbers big enough that they'll blow your brains out.

Comment: Mike: Why do you need to do it infinitely? You only have to do it up to `n`.

Comment: @gabe that's true. nevertheless, i think Poita_ provided the best answer.

Comment: +1: Here is an example to illustrate this answer. Assume we have to compute x^26. Now, 26 = 11010 in binary. The '1' positions signify 16, 8, and 2. So, x^26 = (x^16) * (x^8) * (x^2). Now, if have the series x, x^2, x^4, x^8, x^16 computed, then we can pick selected items of the series and multiple them. Summary: To compute x^n, convert n to binary, find the bit positions (always 2's power) that are 1, compute them starting from the lower side, and multiply the suitable ones.